# How to submit redux-form on specific keypress?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a redux-form integrated React component (redux form v7.0.1) that I am trying to trigger submission when a user presses both `command` and `enter`.

I can successfully check if both keys are pressed, however I cannot submit the form through a function outside of the form using `handleSubmit`.

How do I use `handleSubmit` with my `onSubmit` function?

Methods:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    commandKeyPressed: false
  }

  this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
}

onSubmit(values) {
  console.log(values); // does not log anything
}

handleKeyDown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 91){
    this.setState({ commandKeyPressed: true });
  }

  // [enter] key is pressed after command.
  // the keyCode is stored in component state to 
  // check if it was pressed

  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (this.state.commandKeyPressed) {
      // logs 'trying to submit', but does not call this.onSubmit
      console.log(
        'trying to submit', this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)
      ); 
    }
  }
}
```

Render method:

```
return (
  <div>
    <div className="ama-submit-field reply-container">
      <form ref='commentReplyRef' onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
        <Field
          name="commentReply"
          keyDown={e => this.handleKeyDown(e)}
          keyUp={e => this.handleKeyUp(e)}
          type="input"
          component={myCustomField}
          label={text}>
        </Field>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: this helped me to implement this: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/572#issuecomment-262618476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. I think it's a hack but it works for me.

When I create my form I return `values` from `handleSubmit()` by specifying `onSubmit` in `reduxForm()` options:

```
const CommentForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'Comment',
  onSubmit: values => values,
  validate
})(Comment);

export default CommentForm;
```

I changed `validate` to return an object with an error key for the input field:

```
function validate(values){
  const errors = {};

  if (!values.commentReply){
    errors.commentReply = {
      error: true,
      text: 'Please enter a question.'
    };
  }

  return errors;
}
```

then, in `handleKeyDown`:

```
handleKeyDown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 91) {
    this.setState({commandKeyPressed: true});
  }

  // [enter] key is pressed after command.
  // keyCode is stored in component state to
  // check if it was pressed

  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (this.state.commandKeyPressed) {
      const values = this.props.handleSubmit();

      if (!values.commentReply.hasOwnProperty('error') {
        this.onSubmit(values);
      }
    }
  }
```

This allowed me to trigger my submit function on key press.

I think the better course of action is to move all the submit logic to the `reduxForm` property, however I have a lot of state-specific behavior in my React `onSubmit` function.